# como buscar con regex a partir de palabras de una lista en python

Tags: python, regex

quiero buscar una serie de parabras que inicien con unas iniciales ya establecidas en una lista mediante regex. este es mi código pero no logro que funcione.

Al final quiero almacenar las palabras encontradas en una lista

```
text="contratamos peronas al iniciar el año pero al finalizar el año terminamos los contratos para periodo de vacaciones"

palabras_buscar=["vac","person","inic","fin"]#lista a llenar con palabras que encuentra
lista=[]#lista con las palabras que encontró en la busqueda
for i in palabras_buscar:
    A=re.findall(i+"[\w...]",text , flags=0)
    lista.append(A)
lista
```

gracias por su ayuda

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Código

La mejor manera que se me ocurrió es esta:

```
import re

string = "Tengo unas vacaciones con una persona inicial. enpersonar, envacar, eniniciar, enfinar. Fin."

iniciales = ["vac","person","inic","fin"]

regex = re.compile(r"\b(%s)\w+" % "|".join(re.escape(inicial) for inicial in iniciales))

print("regex:", regex.pattern)

for m in regex.finditer(string):
    print(m[0])
```

Que produce:

```
regex: \b(vac|person|inic|fin)\w+
vacaciones
persona
inicial
```

#### Explicación de la regex

La regex generada va a ser:

```
\b(inicial1|inicial2|inicial3...|inicialn)\w+
```

Que se compone por:

- `\b` el inicio de lo que el modulo re considera una palabra.
- `(inicial1|...)` el | es como el or de Python. Esta expresión coincide con cualquiera de las inciales.
- `\w+` coincide con el resto de la palabra. Un caracter se considera una palabra cuando es una letra, un número o un guion bajo.

#### Explicación de la generación de la regex

Se crea un generador que va generando la versión escapada (es decir, los caracteres que tienen significado en la regex se escapan con una `\`) de cada inicial y luego une todo esto en una sola cadena usando el caracter `|`.